# Normed vector spaces and operator norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $T \colon V \to W$ be a linear map between normed vector spaces $(V, \parallel \cdot \parallel_V)$ and $(W,\parallel \cdot \parallel_W)$ as $$\parallel T \parallel :={\rm sup}\ \{ \parallel T(x) \parallel_W : x \in V,\ \parallel x \parallel_V = 1\}.$$

> I need to show that the definitions 
>   $$\parallel T \parallel :={\rm sup}\ \{ \parallel T(x) \parallel_W : x \in V,\ \parallel x \parallel_V = 1\}$$
>   and
>   $$\parallel T \parallel :={\rm sup}\ \{ \frac{\parallel T(x) \parallel_W }{\parallel x\parallel_V} : x \in V,\ \parallel x \parallel_V \neq 0\}
> $$ are equivalent.

I'm not really sure how to approach this either than to try and manipulate the $\parallel x\parallel_V$ to show that its equal to $1$ (in the case when $\parallel x\parallel_V\neq 0$)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**   Note that $$\| cx\|_V = |c| \| x\|_V$$

Hence $$\frac{\| Tx\|_W}{ \| x\|_V}= \left\| T\left(\frac{1}{\| x\|_V}x\right)\right\|_W$$

and $$ \left\|\frac{1}{\| x\|_V}x\right\|_V=1$$

**Update**

$${\rm sup} \{ \|T(x)\| |\ \| x\|=1\} \geq \| T(\frac{y}{\| y\|}) \|=\frac{\|T(y)\|}{\|y\|}$$ for any $y$.

So norm in first definition is larger than that in second

And   $${\rm sup} \{ \frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|} |\ \| x\|\neq 0\} \geq {\rm sup} \{ \frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|} |\ \| x\|=1\} = {\rm sup} \{ \|T(x)\| |\ \| x\|=1\} $$

So norm in second definition is larger than that in first

Comment: Thank you for your response. So from here I assume that you use this hint in the second definition of $||T||$ to show that $ ||x||_V = 1$ hence we have shown what is required?

Comment: I add some. Please check it.